# Uncaught typeerror cannot read property of null (reading 'value') in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onchange

I get the error "Uncaught typeerror cannot read property of null (reading 'value')" I'm constantly looking for a solution and I don't know what's wrong in the code, Can you help me?

My code

```js
function test(){

for(var i=0; i < 40; i++) {
var name1.value = document.getElementsByClassName('test1')[i];
var address1.value = document.getElementsByClassName('test2')[i];

if( name1.value == "test4"){
address1.value = "test5";
}
else if (name1.value == "test6"){
address1.value = "test7";
}
else if (name1.value == "test8"){
address1.value = "test9";
}
}
}
```

```html
< div class="form grup test1">
< labe for="power-full.names"> Names full</lable>
< input name="power-full.names" list="power-full.names" type="text"
class="form grup test1" onclick="test"(this)">
<datalist type"text" id="power-full.names">
<option value="test4">
<option value="test6">
<option value="test8">
</datalist>
</div>


< div class="form grup test2">
< labe for="power-full.adress"> Adress full</lable>
< input name="power-full.adress" list="power-full.adress" type="text"
class="form grup test2" onclick="test"(this)">
<datalist type"text" id="power-full.adress">
<option value="test5">
<option value="test7">
<option value="test9">
</datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: you probably dont have 40 names as in the for loop you are saying get it 40 times

Comment: I have 40 names, this is sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add the classes so document.getElementsByClassName('test1')[i] returns None. And javascript cannot read value property of None.
To fix -

```
<option class="test1" value="test4">
```

Comment: Onclick works only the problem is that the console shows an error after clicking "Uncaught Uncaught typeerror cannot read property of undefinted (reading 'value') at test.js
at HTMLInpuntElement.onclick (index.html.1)

Answer (score 0):

first: maybe you should use `onchange` event to bound the `input.test1`.

second: change the value of `input.test2`

```js
function test1(ele){
  var address1 = document.getElementById('test2');

  if( ele.value == "test4"){
    address1.value = "test5";
  } else if (ele.value == "test6"){
    address1.value = "test7";
  } else if (ele.value == "test8"){
    address1.value = "test9";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form grup test1">
  <lable for="power-full.names"> Names full</lable>
  <input name="power-full.names" list="power-full.names" type="text"
    class="form grup test1" onchange="test1(this)">
  <datalist type"text" id="power-full.names">
    <option value="test4">
    <option value="test6">
    <option value="test8">
  </datalist>
</div>


<div class="form grup test2">
  <lable for="power-full.adress"> Adress full</lable>
  <input id="test2" name="power-full.adress" list="power-full.adress" type="text"
  class="form grup test2">
  <datalist type"text" id="power-full.adress">
    <option value="test5">
    <option value="test7">
    <option value="test9">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem is that I have to use "getElementsByClassName" because my parent ID is changing. And when I use getElementsByClassName, the function works only shows the error "Uncaught Uncaught typeerror cannot read property of undefinted (reading 'value')"